# A class-based state machine?

Tags: c++, class, templates, state-machine

In C++ I'm trying to make a simple state machine for a game, based on classes.

```
stateMan.setState<mainMenuState>();
```

I have a class with the declaration as:

```
class stateManager
{
  ...
  template <class T>
  void setState(void);
}
```

And the test code as:

```
template <class T>
void stateManager::setState<T>(void)
{
  T* blah = new T;
  delete blah;
}
```

And obviously this doesn't work since `function template partial specialization ‘setState<T>’ is not allowed`.

Would there be a better way to do this besides doing it non-OO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of the member function template should be this:

```
template <class T>
void stateManager::setState(void)
{
   //...
}
```

That is, it should be simply `setState` instead of `setState<T>`. The latter syntax is used in function template specialization. Since `T` is a type parameter, the specialization would be considered as function *partial* template specialization which is not allowed.

Comment: Ah, I originally tried that but got (and still do get) an 'undefined reference to `void stateManager::setState<mainMenuState>()'' error.

Comment: Ah, just figured it out: The method MUST be in the header, not in the cpp file.

Comment: @Konrad: StateManager is not a class template.

Comment: @Jookia: Yes. The method must be in the header file.

Comment: That's not actually true, but in most cases it avoids issues due to how you use the function template elsewhere and because you won't be writing it out again in another TU, or explicitly instantiating it. :) (Remember, C++ doesn't care about "headers".)

Comment: @Jookia: As a general rule of thumb (and it doesn't always work, but...), if you got rid of compiler errors and moved on to getting _linker_ errors, then you're going in the right direction. So you went backwards when you reverted to `stateManager::setState<T>`.

Comment: @Tomalak I usually follow that rule but once I get to linker errors to things within my own code I generally go back and try another way of doing this.

Comment: @Jookia: You should rethink that policy. Linker errors are usually resolved by fixing some silly build mistake, forgetting to define a virtual or by attempting to [implicitly] instantiate a function template in a TU that doesn't contain its definition. These are generally really easy to fix.

Comment: @Tomalak I know that much, but considering I already had code in the cpp file and the header file already had definitions (which all worked fine), I didn't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without the details, but you could do a base `State` class, and the different states inherit from it.

If you still want to use classes for this, you can see an interesting
[example using boost.mpl](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/mpl/example/fsm/player1.cpp).

Answer (score 1):

Another option that avoids templates would be to define a pure virtual base class for your game states, and then pass references to different game-states to your function.  For instance,

```
//pure virtual base class that will define the state interfaces
class base_state { /*...*/ }; 

//a derived state class
class mainMenuState : public base_state { /*...*/ }; 

class stateManager
{
    //...

    //you can pass any derived base_state to this function
    void setState(base_state* state); 
};
```